# Why I am getting Parse error: syntax error when I use 'wp_is_mobile'?

Tags: mobile, custom-header

I am getting following error message :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/otcpaneluser/public_html/mytheme/header.php on line 1
```

My header.php have very simple lines of code. Those are:

```
    <?php
    if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) { // desktop header
        echo 'I am the desktop header';
    }
    else {
        echo 'I am the mobile header';
    }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="lePo6W0p7rXhyUR2Yd21QNuJey6t9b240pkJlPbZJe4" />

  <head></head>
  <body>....</body>
</html>
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve this??

Comment: The header.php should be in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php, are you looking in the right file?

Comment: yeah.. header.php is in the **mytheme** folder

Comment: it works fine if I do not use **wp_is_mobile()**

Comment: Post your complete header file, it seems that you are adding that code right at the top, which you should not do

Comment: ooh.. @PieterGoosen thanks for that.. exactly that's what I am doing.. check my updated code.. so how can I solve it??

Comment: Your header file is invalid

Comment: could you please explain bit more specific some thing like how to solve this and how to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be executing anything before your `DOCTYPE` tag. That will all be invalid code and is also the issue leading to your error.

In general, any output like above should be done after the `<head></head>` tags, although some prefer to hook into the `wp_head` hook to execute functions like your code. I do prefer however to move such code after the closing `head` tag.

So your solution would be to move your conditional code to just after the closing head tag